# How to change the name of a tf.summary.* op (within a session)

Tags: tensorflow

If my graph contains a summary node, is there any way for me to change the node's name to something else after I have started a session with this graph?

I want the ability to dynamically affect the name that a summary node uses when generating the summary protobuf string.  It would be ideal if I could pass a placeholder in as the name parameter, but that does not currently work.

Changing the summary name doesn't seem like it would be technically impossible to do with TF (even if it isn't currently implemented).  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your summary `name` can be a placeholder.

Thus

```
name_ = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=())
value_to_log_ = tf.placeholder(tf.<yourtype>,shape=(<yourshape>)

summary = tf.summary.<yourchoice>(name_, value_to_log_)
```

Then, within a session `sess` you just feed the desired name, in the following "summary 1"

```
sess.run(summary, feed_dict={
                  name_: "summary 1", value_to_log_: nicevalue})
```

In the example above I used a placeholder also for the value to log, you can use a standard tensor or whatever you want

Comment: The use of a placeholder in lieu of a string for the summary's name results in "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".